# Incrementing resgister in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

My professor gave us a worksheet on MIPS but never really gave examples so I need to assume my interpretations of the instructions are correct. I'm fairly certain that most of the questions require ADD and ADDI, but I want to double check I'm using it correctly.

"Provide a sequence that performs:

increments register $15 by 2010

I think that this is ADDI $15, $15, 2010

Would ADD work better? Would there be a way to implement that?

There is also a question asking for a sequence that "puts value 12345 in a word at memory location 65,528" that confuses me.

Answer (score 0):

`addi` is the canonical way to add a literal (What we call an 'immediate' value, hence the `i` in `addi`) to the value of a register.

If you're not allowed to use `addi` (Some schools don't), you can combine `add` and `li`. `li $reg, imm` loads the value of `imm` (A numeric literal) into the register `$reg`.

In terms of what works better, if there's any difference at all it'll be negligible. If anything at all,  `addi` will be faster by one CPU cycle. The difference is no negligible that for most purposes it doesn't matter. In an academic setting, it almost definitely doesn't matter.

As for your second question: it's not very clear wording, but you're being asked to store an immediate value into a location in memory. Unless your professor really didn't talk about the instructions at all, you should have at least one instruction on your worksheet that can do something like that.

> Look at `sw`. You'll need to do a little preprocessing, but it'll get you on your way.

Comment: _"If you're not allowed to use addi (Some schools don't)"_. Huh. That's weird. Considering that `li` is a pseudo-instruction while `addi` is an actual MIPS instruction.

Comment: @Michael it depends on what the course is about. Any course that's actually *about* programming in assembly will probably let you use it, but I once took a course that about compiling that required us to use `lis` instead

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples how to do it, not necessarily "optimal" instruction sequences;

`ADDI` adds an immediate value to a register, and stores the result in another register, while `ADD` adds two registers and stores a value in a third register.

For example, your "add 2010" task could be done either way, although simpler with `ADDI` since you'd need to store the value 2010 in a register first to use `ADD`;

```
ADDI $15, $15, 2010
```

or (for example);

```
ORI $1, $0, 2010         ; store the value 2010 in $1
ADD $15, $15, $1         ; add $1 with $15, store result in $15
```

In this case `ADDI` is simpler. It would make more sense to use `ADD` if the value you want to add won't fit in the 16 bits signed value allowed by `ADDI`s immediate value.

As an example for your second question, you can easily store the required values in registers;

```
ORI $14, $0, 12345
ORI $15, $0, 65528
```

...and then you can just use `SW` to store the word;

```
SW $14, 0($15)
```

If your professor's instruction list does not give enough information, [this page](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html) is a pretty good starting point, although the MIPS instruction set is *very* well documented on the web if you look around a bit.

Comment: `ADDUI` is not a MIPS instruction. `LUI` loads a 16 bit constant into the upper 16 bits of a register and zeroes the lower 16 bits. To load a 32 bit constant perform a `LUI` followed by an `ADDI` or `ORI`.

Comment: `ADDIU` (and `ADDI`) only loads a 16 bit signed constant into the lower 16 bits of a register. You need to use `LUI` to load a constant into the upper 16 bits.

Comment: Sorry for being so pedantic here :-) The immediate value is a 16 bit *signed* constant, so 65528 is not a legal value. The `U` in opcodes like `ADDIU`, `SUBU` means "do not trap on integer overflow", it does not mean "unsigned".

Comment: @markgz Ah, _now_ I see what you mean \*bops head\*. Changed the misuse of ADDIU, thanks for correcting me :)